# Every Model get distorted like this when placed far away from the center why?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, animation-nodes

These two models are placed at -36216.6 m. [image]

At 0 M
[image]

At -36216.6 m
[image]

Comment: you don't mention your camera location or camera lense settings, nor how large the models are (human size or monster).   I doubt you'll receive any help due to the lack of information.

Comment: Your models are 7 times farther than what is recommanded by Blender's manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/limits.html.

Comment: Height of the model is 1.33012 m its a default model from the mixamo and i have not added any camera yet. And i will go through what Lutzi has provided and come back again and thanks for the reply.

Comment: Distorted like what? How is anyone supposed to know how your model should look in the first place?

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283626/increase-floating-point-precision-with-large-scene-and-parented-objects#comment487569_283626). This is due to what we call a float precision loss. A lengthy explanation could be this: [c++ - Why loss of floating point precision makes rendered objects vibrate? - Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/163936/why-loss-of-floating-point-precision-makes-rendered-objects-vibrate).

Comment: Hello, aeroplug.. @L0Lock's suggestion has to be the main suspect, here.. can you indicate the distortion you refer to, by comparison with an undistorted version, please?

Comment: Hi @Robin Betts, i have added the two images.

Comment: @L0Lock, thanks for the reply i will go through that Article.

Comment: One more thing, this happens only in Cycle but works good on Evee.